# Ansible F5 Module Enable Virtual server

Tags: ansible, f5

I am trying to enable/disable existing individual virtual server using ansible. The following code is working properly when the type of VIP is standard. But, if the type is different like Performance-l4 it is asking for additional parameters(profiles) to be passed. Is this normal behavior(it is trying to overwrite the existing values.) or is my way of doing it not right.
How to preserve the existing state and simply enable/disable the VIP in F5. Kindly guide me.

```
tasks:
- name: Change state of virtual server
  bigip_virtual_server:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    name: /App/vip1
    destination: 198.51.100.1
    port: 443
    snat: "Automap"
    state: "enabled"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this and the Performance L4 server type requires a protocol profile and it does not apply a default one like it does for certain things with a Standard one. ie. when you specific port 443, it automatically throws in a http profile.

I checked in the GUI and when you specify the Performance L4 profile, it does apply the fastL4 profile as the default.

In your situation, if you wanted you could just use the REST API: https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/icontrol-rest/APIRef_tm_ltm_virtual.html

PATCH https://IP-of-BIGIP/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/{nameofvip}

Body:

{
"disable": true
}

Also worth double checking in the #ansible on the Slack support channel: https://f5cloudsolutions.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for your time @buulam, So can I assume that even for enable/disable these values should be passed along with state.

Comment: @user2670623 - right, looks like it for that VIP type. Are you deploying the VIP with Ansible in the first place?

Comment: No, it is already available. I am trying to enable/disable it.

Comment: I did it with the help of API.  Thanks for your suggestions. There is a new module introduced as bigip_gtm_virtualserver which directly supports enable/disable VIP. but it seems that will work only GTM(Global Traffic Manager) is enabled.

Comment: Oh ok excellent. I guess it depends on how you want to manage things. If you want to eventually be totally Infrastructure as Code, you'll want to explore managing everything through F5 AS3 declarations - which you can still do through Ansible if that's a preferred tool. Cheers